# Lost about 1% reputation after data center migration

Tags: support, reputation, outage

After the planned outage because of the migration to the new data center last night my stack overflow reputation dropped from 4280 to 4245:

[image: 4280]

---

After a browser refresh:

[image: 4245]

The history doesn't show any downvotes. What went wrong?

Comment: Ooops, they left that bit of your rep behind. It's on the next interstate bus.

Comment: OK let's hope that the bus stops here in Europe ;)

Comment: Curious: how did you get the first screenshot? (Every now and then I wish my browser would keep a copy off all pages, even when I refresh. But that would be hard for Ajax- driven content.)

Comment: iPhone iOS 6.1 seems to keep old contents even when I pressed on the drop down button

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Though we restored all data logs from Oregon in the move, the last 5 minutes from various sites didn't make it, even though we took and restored backups during and well after the sites were in read-only mode.

We're still investigating why this happened as this certainly wasn't my intent when building the steps for our migration.  We wanted no downtime (read-only only) and no data loss...obviously that didn't happen and for that I apologize.  This was my plan and something didn't work correctly.

We'll spend a good chunk of time tomorrow finding out why this happened and seeing what we can do to restore the major items to New York - it's by no means a simple task but if it's not a insane effort to do so, we'll try and recover the few minutes of posts, comments and votes - things like edits likely aren't worth it in this case.

Hang on a few days, and we'll see what we can do.  Jarrod has already done a good deal of work on seeing what's missing, I'll start assisting tomorrow on what we can do for a restore if at all possible.

Comment: No worries, I am sure it was a tough job, so good luck!

Comment: Is the deletion of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932306/how-does-startcoroutine-yield-return-pattern-really-work-in-unity#comment20723026_12932306) related? The guy was already asking me why this has gone.

Comment: @Kay: It is only -18 rep (2 up, 1 down).

Comment: I've unfortunately lost two answers, to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252300/how-do-i-edit-the-commands-that-start-a-service-in-ubuntu-12) and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253037/stuck-in-single-user-mode). I answered them in the minutes before the lockdown. They were both upvoted once, if that helps you.

Comment: Any idea what the result of this was? (just curious)